# Wrong Port in Horizon Link on Kubernetes

Tags: horizon

I'm running [Stellar QuickStart](https://github.com/stellar/quickstart) on a Kubernetes Cluster, but the links contain the Pod port when it shouldn't.

Here's the Kubernetes setup

- Pod => Container Port = 8000
- ClusterIP Service => Port = 8000, TargetPort = 8000
- Ingress Service => Ports = 443,80

The actual site is https://horizon-test.rivalcoins.money and it produces the following

```
"account": {
  "href": "https://horizon-test.rivalcoins.money:8000/accounts/{account_id}",
  "templated": true
},
```

I want `account.href` to be `https://horizon-test.rivalcoins.money` instead of `https://horizon-test.rivalcoins.money:8000`

Any help is appreciated.